# h2o automl predict NaN column instead of "p1"

Tags: python, h2o, automl

After training h2o, if I want to predict classes for a dataframe like `hf_pred`, I get NaN columns like following:

```
predictions = model.predict(hf_pred)

print(f'predictions: {predictions} ')
```

[image]

Any idea why the columns tag are `0.0` and `nan` ?

Comment: Can you print out what the classes are called in the training data?  It looks like they are "0.0" and "nan".   If your training set is called `train` and your response column is stored as `y`, then you can print: `train[y].levels()` and it will show you the class names.

Comment: Thanks Erin and more power to you all at Automl.

You were right, the classes were 0 and nan.